# Scala Overriding Equals for a Certain Type

Tags: scala, equals, case-class

I have a method that works on two sequences. I use the groupBy function which in turn works on the equals method to actually group the elements that I ask it to group. Here is the method that I have:

```
  def mergeFunc[T][B](seq1: Seq[(T, B)], seq2: Seq[(T, B)]) = {
    val result = seq1.groupBy(_._1).mapValues(_.foldLeft(0)((total, current) => total + current._2))
    ......
    ......
  }
```

Now in the function above, how could I make the groupBy also work for my case classes? For example., I have a case class that is a composition of other types (which may or may not be a case class) and I do not want to go and write the equals implementation for all of those types. How could I implicitly or explicitly specify that for the case classes that I pass to this method like:

```
 mergeFunc[TypeA][Long](Seq(TypeA, Long), Seq(TypeA, Long))
```

How can I guarantee that the groupBy works on an equals method that I would like to pass to this method as a parameter?

Comment: 2 options — make them all case classes, or make an overload of `groupBy` that takes an `Ordering` to use it instead of `equals` method on objects

Comment: Making all of them as case class does not work. Can you elaborate on the second option? How can I call the overloaded groupBy? or rather how could I pass an Ordering?

Comment: hm, you can look at source code of `groupBy` method and extend it to support custom `Ordering`. wait, maybe it's already there... I gonna check

Comment: I believe your second code block is incorrect. I think you meant this: `mergeFunc[TypeA][Long](Seq[(TypeA, Long)], Seq[(TypeA, Long)])`.

Comment: For the non-case classes, I can't see any way around writing an `equals` that captures the desired equality semantics you require. My stock advice is to read chapter 28 of Programming in Scala carefully before proceeding.

Comment: I do not want it to act on the equals method, but rather in my case two objects are equal if they meet certain conditions and I have written those conditions separately. I now only want a way such that the collections method operate on my custom equal method rather than the default equals method. I also do not want to write the equals method on my non-case classes.